# Remove transparent overlay UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

How do you remove the transparent black overlay that animates over the source table view when you activate a UISearchBar?

Can you somehow get to the UIView responsible and set it's alpha to 0?

Or is there a way to display an empty searchResultsTableView on top of the black overlay?

Comment: To clarify more. Is there a way to display the searchResultsTableView (the tableview which is controlled by the searchDisplayController to display the searchResults), before a user initiates a search? OR is there a way to hide the black overlay that the searchDisplayController draws over the original datasource tableview?

Answer (score 6):

```
po [self.view subviews]

(id) $1 = 0x0a3155f0 <__NSArrayM 0xa3155f0>(
<ATShadowTableView: 0xc341600; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 44; 320 411); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xa627200>; layer = <CALayer: 0xa626d30>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>,
<UISearchBar: 0xa618f40; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = ''; layer = <CALayer: 0xa619040>>,
<UIControl: 0xa329fc0; frame = (0 44; 320 455); alpha = 0.8; opaque = NO; animations = { opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0xa32b4e0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0xa32a060>>
)
```

Last object (`UIControl`) in self.subview is what we want to remove. So

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
...
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeOverlay) withObject:nil afterDelay:.01f];
}

- (void)removeOverlay
{
    [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: This still works in iOS 7, however it now seems to be a  `UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView` instead of a `UIControl`. I'd also like to add, since it wasn't clear in this answer, that the overlay appears in `-searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch`, but needs to be removed in `-searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch` after a very short delay. If you remove it it in `-searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch` then the overlay will briefly appear before disappearing again.

Comment: I disagree, this does not actually work on iOS7. Indeed, the overlay will disappear but the table view will not be reloaded after a search bar text change anymore!

Comment: I was able to get this to work in iOS7 by using

[[self.view.subviews lastObject] setHidden:YES];

[[self.view.subviews lastObject] setHidden:NO];

at the appropriate times.

Answer (score 0):

Always have it display some cells, even if there aren't any results from the search yet. You can accomplish this through the usual UITableViewDelegate/UITableViewDataSource methods. Just be careful because you now are dealing with the original table view, the search table view, and the search table view with dummy cells in it, and all the UITableViewDelegate/UITableViewDataSource methods need to be aware of this.

Comment: How do I set the UISearchDisplayControllerDelegate.searchResultsTableView to have a different datasource when it first loads? And then switch to the searchResults datasource when someone starts searching?

Comment: If I were you, I'd use the same data source, and just check if ([filteredListContent count] == 0). If so, return some blank cells, (tableView height/row height) number of rows per section, 1 section, and just deselect any row that is selected.

Comment: In fact, now that I look at the documentation, that may be the only way as there's no way to observe the text in the UISearchBar for changes.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I don't think my question was clear enough. I'm trying to display the empty search results before a searchString has been defined. It doesn't look like that is possible.

Comment: Like all good things, it's not possible in a non-slightly hacky fashion. I'll post a fuller solution in an edit later.